# How to hide / obfuscate the function of an IC?

Tags: obfuscation, integrated-circuit

Let's say I have an IC (integrated circuit) and I want to hide it's function. What would be best practice to do that?

- Removing the markings with sandpaper or acid?
- (E.g. atmega328, ATtiny85,... ) How to avoid that anyone could find out what program sketch is running on it?
- Connecting a few useless other ICs without function to it?

Imagine now you found one of these black bugs (IC) without markings and without other components. What could you do to get the program sketch running on it?

Comment: commission a custom µC with non-standard pinout. When connecting the chip the normal way it instead gets fried

Comment: I think most AVRs have a fuse that can prevent reading of the program memory. You should check your microcontroller's datasheet.